# How do I check my list to see if it contains only one value or more than one?

Tags: scheme, lisp

Here's what I have so far:

```
(DEFINE (swap lst)
  (COND ((NULL? lst) lst)
    (IF (lst --------))
))
```

I'm new to Scheme so I'm a little bit confused right now. For this function I'm supposed to check for a few things:

1. Is the list empty? If so, print out the unchanged empty list.
2. Is the list a single atom (element)? If so, print out the unchanged list.
3. If the list is not empty and has more than one atom, count out pairs and swap 
   the orders of those pairs.
       i.e. If my list is (a b c d e f g) 
            then my function should return (b a d c f e g)

My primary question is how I go about checking my list to see if it has a single value or more than one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking if a list has no elements is simple:

```
(null? lst)
```

Now, how can we verify if it has a single element? it's very similar to the previous case, we just check to see if the element after the current is the empty list:

```
(null? (cdr lst))
```

After that, the solution to the problem is obtained from the definition:

```
(define (swap lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) lst)
        ((null? (cdr lst)) lst)
        (else <do your thing>)))
```

For the last case, take care of `cons`ing the second element, to the first element, to the result of recursively processing the rest of the list; also remember that in this case for obtaining the "rest" we must advance over *two* elements at a time.

Comment: I happened to find a response of yours on a similar question here on SO:
 
`(DEFINE (swap lst)
  (COND
        ((NULL? lst) lst)
        ((NULL? (CDR lst)) lst)
        (ELSE (CONS (CADR lst)
                        (CONS (CAR lst)
                                (swap (CDDR lst)))))`

But when I showed it to my professor he said he was iffy about the ELSE part. What do you think?